Animated polyline in @rnmapbox/maps in ReactNative
As I've integrated map using @rnmapbox/maps and I want to show animated polyline between 2 markers like this, I go through the all the docs and blogs but found all the docs regarding to React Js but need9 in ReactNative. Please help me here do we've this feature in @rnmapbox/maps or not ?
